# Undefined reference for a C++ function when called from C function

Tags: c++, c, extern

I am trying to call a C++ function from a C function and i see a undefined reference to a function written .cc file, Below is the code. What am i missing?

externcpp.cc

```
#include <iostream>
 #include "example.h"
 using namespace std;
 int main ()
 {
    cout << "I am " << __func__ << "In File " << __FILE__;
    return 0;
 }
 void example_fun()
 {
    cout << "I am" << __func__ << "in File __FILE__";
 }
```

externc.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "example.h"
int test1()
{
    printf(" I am [%s] and from File [%s]\n",__func__,__FILE__);
    printf("Calling C++ Function from C\n");
    example_fun();
    return 0;
}
```

example.h

```
#ifndef EXAMPLE_H
#define EXAMPLE_H

#ifdef __cpluscplus
#define EXTERNC extern "C"
#else
#define EXTERNC
#endif

EXTERNC void example_fun();
#endif
```

And used following commands for compilation and linking

```
g++ -c -o externcpp.o externcpp.cc -Wall
gcc -c -o externc.o externc.c -Wall
g++ -o output externcpp.o externc.o
```

Regards,

Comment: Please add the error message.

Comment: Why is there a trailing `{` on your `#define EXTERNC?`  It seems to never be closed.

Comment: externc.o: In function 'test1' externc.c: (.text+0x2d) : undefined reference to 'example_fun' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Di you really mean C+C+?

Comment: Typo questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes i mean C++ function called from C. Got the answer!!! Thanks

Comment: I rolled back your last edit because it removed the error, which made the question even more useless.

Comment: Agreed @juanchopanza

Answer (score 9):

It's supposed to be `#ifdef __cplusplus`, not `#ifdef __cpluscplus` as in your code above. Check your spelling.

Comment: Ew, those are errors you can stare at for hours without seeing them. Good catch!

Comment: Yes that was the error after making that change i got the required result thanks to all. Thanks @AndreyT